# Exponential formula for Poisson random measure

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process, levy-processes

We want to prove the following result.

- Let $M$ be a Poisson random measure with intensity measure $\mu$.
- Then for every measurable set $B$ such that $\mu(B) < \infty$ and for all functions $f$ such that $\int_B e^{f(x)} \mu(dx) < \infty$

$$ \mathbb{E} \exp \left\{ \int_B f(x) M(dx) \right\} = \exp \left\{ \int_B  (e^{f(x)}-1 ) \mu(dx) \right\}$$

We should condition by the expectation on $\mu(B)$.

From [Course Online](http://perso.univ-lemans.fr/%7Eapopier/enseignement/ENSTA/poly_ENSTA_proc_levy.pdf):

---

**Definition 1.6** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $E\subset \mathbb{R}^k$, and $\rho$ a measure on $(E,\mathcal{E})$. A **Poisson random measure on $E$ with intensity $\rho$** is a function with values in $\mathbb{N}$:
$$ \begin{array}{ccccc}
M : & \Omega \times \mathcal{E} & \to & \mathbb{N} & \text{s.t.} \\
& (\omega, A) & \mapsto & M(\omega, A), & 
\end{array}$$

1. $\forall \omega \in \Omega$, $M(\omega, \cdot)$ is a Radon measure on $E$, that is, $\forall A \in \mathcal{E}$ measurable and bounded, $M(A) < \infty$ is a r.v. with values in $\mathbb{N}$;
2. $\forall A \in \mathcal{E}$, $M(\cdot,A) = M(A)$ is a Poisson r.v. with parameter $\rho(A)$;
3. for any $A_1, \dots, A_n$ disjointed sets, the r.v. $M(A_1), \dots, M(A_n)$ are independents.

Now let $M$ be a Poisson random measure with intensity measure $\mu$ and let $A$ be a measurable subset s.t. $0 < \mu(A) < +\infty$. Then the following two random measures on the subsets of $A$ have the same distribution conditionally on $M(A)$:

- $M|_A$, the restriction of $M$ to $A$.
- $\widehat{M}\!{}_A$ defined by $\widehat{M}\!{}_A(B) = \sharp\{X_i \in B\}$ for all measurable subsets $B$ of $A$, where $X_i$, $i = 1, \dots, M(A)$ are independent and distributed on $A$ with the law $\frac{\mu(\mathrm{d}x)}{\mu(A)}$.

This implies in particular that

$$ \boxed{\mathbb{E}\exp\left(\int_{A}f(X) \, M(dx)\right) = \exp\left( \int_{A} (e^{f(x)} - 1) \mu(dx) \right)} \tag{1.7}$$

for any function $f$ such that $\int_A e^{f(x)} \mu(dx) < +\infty$. This can be obtained by conditioning the expectation on $\mu(A)$ and by the previous result on $M|_A$ and $\widehat{M}\!{}_A$.

---

> **Q.** We have a proof here, could you explain the first line $E(e^{iuX} \mid N=n)$ ?

---

[image: proof]

Comment: What is $\int_B f(x)M(dx)$? Is it a summation $\sum_{x\in M} f(x)$?

Comment: what means $M(dx)$? First time I see it, it represent the measure $M dP$ or something like that?

Comment: This author must be construing $\text{“}\mathbb N\text{”}$ to mean $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}.$ One must hope that he said so, since often that symbol is taken to refer to $\{1,2,3,\ldots\},$ excluding $0. \qquad$

Comment: What is your question? Proving that the MGF of the Poisson random measure $M$ is given by the formula as in the first photo? If then, the idea is routine: first prove the formula when $f$ is simple and then take limit.

Comment: Yes, I am stuck in the first line of the proof.

Comment: I suspect that $N$ is simply a typo of $X$. Then what the author is doing in the proof is obvious: conditioning on the value of $X$. Also, note that the lemma mentioned above allows you to realize the law of $X$ as the compound Poisson r.v. $$\sum_{i=1}^{M(E)}g(Y_i), $$ where $Y_i$'s are i.i.d. and sampled from the law $\mu(\mathrm{d}y)/\mu(E)$. This proves the first equation in page 50.

Answer (score 1):

- We fix a subset $A$
- For  given $\omega$, $M(A)$ is a random variable that follows a Poisson distribution of parameter $( \mu(A))$
- ${M|}_A$ the restriction of $M$ the Poisson random measure on the subset $A$ admits a representation
- For $B \subset A$, ${M|}_A(B)= \# \{ Y_i \in B , i \in [1, \dots N]  \}$ where $N$ follows a a Poisson distribution of parameter $( \mu(A))$ and $Y_i$ is distributed according to $P(Y_i \in B) = \dfrac{ \mu(B)}{ \mu{B}}$
- That is to say, we draw first $N$
- Therefore ${M|}_A(B) = \sum_{k=1}^N \mathbb{1}_{Y_i \in B}$
- and $\int f(x) {M|}_A(dx) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(Y_i)$
- it explains the proof